# GLGenVertexArrays giving me an invalid memory address

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I am new to openGL and I have search around the web and followed some tutorials but I am still having an issue. When I run my project I get a error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0000000000000. Access Violation executing location 0x0000000000000
```

Below is my code that I am executing that is causing this exception and would love some help on nailing down my issue:

```
GLuint vertextBuffer;
GLuint vertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);
glGenBuffers(1, &vertextBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertextBuffer);
```

The exception occurs when I try to bind both the VBO and VAO.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Suspect you forgot to [init your extension pointers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).  `glGenVertexArrays()` is probably NULL.  Edit in a [mcve] so we can verify.

Comment: You have to load the corresponding extension for all functions > OpenGL 1.1. You can, for example, use [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) for this

Comment: I am using glew already for this @BDL

Comment: Have you called `glewInit()` with `glewExperimental` set to true? And please add a MCVE.

Comment: @BDL  I just realized you have to call glewInit() to use those functions. I had not seen that on any of the tutorials until you mentioned it. I added it and it started working!~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All functions and extensions of OpenGL > 1.1 have to be loaded in order to be used. This can be done, for example, by using [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) which has to be initialized as follows:

```
glewExperimental = true;
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err)
{
    /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
    ...
}
```

(Example code is from http://glew.sourceforge.net/)